# Linux system is freezing when app crashes

Tags: linux

Huge problem: I have gotten myself into a situation where my system freeze completely and I have to restart my computer each time my app hits a certain bug. The complete system explodes: the mouse, the sound, everything. Nothing works but to force restart by holding the button.

Is there any way of running the app in a way that it can't bring down the whole system? I have tried running it through llvmpipe as the graphics driver because I thought I was crashing the graphics driver - didn't help. Any tips on how I can debug my app without exploding my system? Can't debug when I have to reboot all the time.

No, my computer is not broken.

Comment: if it's "your" app, you have the source code, and you can recompile with debugging support, then run in debugger to get close to what is causing the crash. Of course you can't let it crash, you have to step thru looking for likely suspects in memory allocations etc.  Else if you're lucky, a VM as PeterG mentions. Good luck.

Comment: It's a C++ app using OpenGL. No hardware specific hacking or anything.  Tested in XFCE and GNOME 3. Hangs the sound, mouse, keyboard. Triggers and takes 2 seconds before the system hangs. Tried setting the process priority to lowest. I use Mesa3D Intel drivers. Have tried llvmpipe drivers.

Comment: I have seen a similar hang when compiling on 8 cores using MinGW64. May be a kernel bug, I mean how bad your code is, it shouldn't bring down a protected mode OS.

Comment: I found the bug, it was an infinite loop inside a lock, causing the OpenGL scene to hang. Guess you shouldn't do that or the whole system will blow up in your face. Maybe it's a Mesa bug then?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a program running in a virtual machine should be unable to bring down the host system.

Answer (score 1):

1. **It's hard so say for sure without knowing more about your setup and application**, but it sounds like some kind of memory leak that doesn't get caught by the compiler (or maybe from a live coding language).
2. **Check your code for any while-loops with conditions that aren't met**, or other kinds of recursion issues.
3. **If you still can't find your bug**, please post your coding language, debugger and possibly the actual code as well.

Answer (score 1):

What does your program do? Is it:

- a graphical program (do you have proprietary drivers?)
- something that scans the filesystem (it is messing around in /proc?)
- something that deal with particular types of hardware?

You might consider enabling Sys-Req and a crash kernel. When the system hangs, assuming you can still use the keyboard, you can cause a system reset which should capture a kernel dump.

Sending debugging messages out a serial port can be a useful way to capture information.